# Adding the values of a series to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, addition

I'm trying to add the values of a series to a dataframe. I'm not trying to add the column to the end of the dataframe i.e. create an extra column in the data frame.

I have a series that is the same length as the columns n the data frame. I would like to add the values in the series to each column in the frame.
I have tried `Dataframe.add()` but it did not work.

Code:
Dataframe (named reader):

```
     Current track blade 1   Current track blade 2   
0                -8.577881               -0.333252  
1                -6.284912                5.294434    
2                 6.269775               11.229490     
3                 5.253418               10.187260     
4               -16.088380               -2.967773
```

Series (named abs_track) to add to each column:

```
    Current abs track
0            3503.125
1            3517.333
2            3504.778
3            3476.127
4            3477.776
```

`reader=reader+abs_track` and `reader.add('abs_track')` give:

```
     Current abs track   Current track blade 1   Current track blade 2    


0                  NaN                     NaN                     NaN                     
1                  NaN                     NaN                     NaN 
2                  NaN                     NaN                     NaN   
3                  NaN                     NaN                     NaN   
4                  NaN                     NaN                     NaN
```

Any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use apply function:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Current track blade 1":[-8.577881, -6.284912, 6.269775, 5.253418, -16.088380], "Current track blade 2": [-0.333252, 5.294434, 11.229490,10.187260,-2.967773]})
>>> s1 = pd.Series([3503.125, 3517.333, 3504.778, 3476.127, 3477.776])
>>> df1.apply(lambda x: x + s1)
   Current track blade 1  Current track blade 2
0            3494.547119            3502.791748
1            3511.048088            3522.627434
2            3511.047775            3516.007490
3            3481.380418            3486.314260
4            3461.687620            3474.808227
```

Comment: @EdChum no problem, +1 for your answer

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass the parameter [`axis=0`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) to achieve what you want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Current track blade 1":[-8.577881, -6.284912, 6.269775, 5.253418, -16.088380], "Current track blade 2": [-0.333252, 5.294434, 11.229490,10.187260,-2.967773]})
s = pd.Series([3503.125, 3517.333, 3504.778, 3476.127, 3477.776])

df.add(s, axis=0)

Out[58]:
   Current track blade 1  Current track blade 2
0            3494.547119            3502.791748
1            3511.048088            3522.627434
2            3511.047775            3516.007490
3            3481.380418            3486.314260
4            3461.687620            3474.808227
```

This will add column-wise rather than row-wise which is the default.